# Visio: all text became covered with gray pattern

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2007, microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2007

Suddenly **all** the text in **all** the documents (including any new document) looks like this:

[image]

But if I double-click it to edit, the text is indeed there:

[image]

I think it's some global Visio setting, but I couldn't find the culprit. Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Options** -> **Advanced**
in the **Display** section
and set **Greek text under** to a smaller font size. It's normally 4pt I think.

Comment: No, Greeking is a way of improving display performance by not showing the detail in very small text. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greeking

Comment: Oww, live and learn. It all makes sense now, thanks. Booting up the laptop to check your solution now.